# can i know why this model has loss=nan and 0 accuracy?

Tags: dataframe, machine-learning, model, loss-function

[colab link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1H3bAw2P1x-RzSUOkKbBO9g6YHBcAXCGV?hl=ko#scrollTo=lCNa4C0rPZcu)(this is an assignment, so there are lots of footnotes:) )

i have no idea why this model shows nan loss and 0 accracy

i checked loss function, added dropna and coded deletion of negative values, much more things which may have the possibility that derives nan loss that i could find on google with search

is this just occuring simply because the dataframe i want to train is not suitable for learning?

[this is data site](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/mohithsairamreddy/salary-data)

Answer (score 0):

in the code link use `df.dropna(inplace=True)` to save the dropping of Nan values to the original dataframe. Hope this helps !!!!